# Questionable Mechanic HELP

Tags: battery

Having a lot of issues with a mechanic, to many issues to write about. He told me today after I asked to see the diagnostic report that I paid for that they could not run a full diagnostic on my car since my battery died, when that happens it erases all error codes. But I still had to pay for the serivce. This seems wrong but would like an opinion.

Comment: Welcome to the site @marisa, it would help if you could tell us the make, model and year of the car as well as the problems you have had with it.

Comment: "Having a lot of issues with a mechanic, to many issues to write about" So why do you continue doing business with this mechanic? Yes it is wrong what they did, pay for something they could not do? Really!

Comment: Absolutely wrong what they did.  A respectable mechanic (as a business man) would not charge you in a case like this.  I am suspicious of the whole thing.